# How to turn off notifications from Microsoft Edge extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, microsoft-edge, notifications

I am constantly receiving notifications from the Edge browser due to an extension I installed to enforce some time limits on certain websites. Every time I visit one of those websites a notification appears with the time left.

How do I stop notifications from certain extensions? I imagine it is similar for Google Chrome.

[image: extension]

Comment: Have you asked the extension's developpers?

Comment: @Toto the extension itself can only be installed if you accept the notification access. My question is if I can bypass this in the browser settings

Comment: That's true : I installed this extension and in "View web permissions" I can't change the value of "Notifications" to "Block". I'm afraid that there is no solution for this one extension - it just won't let you block it.